# Constructing a function with N zeros inside the unit disk,

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, analyticity

Find all functions $f(z)$ such that:

a) $f$ is analytic in some region containing |z| $\le$ 1

b) $|f| = 1$ on $|z| =1$

c) $f$ has N simple zeros $z_1, ... , z_N$ inside $|z| < 1$ and no other zeros on $|z| \le 1$.

Any ideas are welcome.

I had initially thought that $z^N$ was a good candidate but it only fulfills parts a) and b); its zeros are at the origin, of multiplicity N.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard construction here called a [Blaschke product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) that does this. Such products are constructed from the standard conformal map from $\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ that swaps $0$ and $a$; that is,

$$f_a(z) = \frac{|a|}{a} \frac{a - z}{1 - \overline{a} z}$$

This map preserves the boundary of the disk, and hence has absolute value $1$ on the boundary of the disk (as do finite products of such maps).

Comment: Hi @user, so do we have one function or $N$ functions, i.e., one function for each zero $a_n$? Thanks,

Comment: @User001 Take a product of functions that look like this, one for each zero.

Comment: That's so cool ... thanks so much @user - I will verify the details now :-)

Comment: You're very welcome, @User001.

Comment: Hi @user, hmm...how do we know that with this product, the zeros $a_n$ are *inside* the disk?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001 You specify the zero of the function: It's at $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you still have to worry about finding $all$ such functions. To do this you will want to show that if $g$ is holomorphic on some $D(0,R)$ with $R>1,$ $|g|=1$ on $\{|z|=1\},$ and $g\ne 0$ on the closed unit disc, then $g$ is constant.